# Dynamically logging in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

Currently I'm having a spring boot application and for each class like `SampleClass` that I would like to have a log I need to initialize the logger like this:

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleClass.class);
```

Which means that we need statically send the classname to the `getLogger` method.
I was thinking of creating a loggable interface and everytime a class implements this interface, it dynamically finds the class name and properly write the log to the outputstream with proper classname. 
I googled to find a proper solution but every example is specifically sending the classname in the compile time. Does spring have this ability?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923971/why-calling-loggerfactory-getlogger-every-time-is-not-recommended !

Comment: No, but I created an interface ILoggable and I created a log object the same way that mentioned in the link. Created a Log class and implemented ILoggable. when I'm using the log object inside Log class the output saying that the log belongs to ILoggable instead of Log class. the output is something like this " c.c.c.service.ILoggable                  : test" instead of " c.c.c.service.Log                  : test"

Comment: You have 2 options: either use `private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass())` as your log definition, which you can declare as a live template in IntelliJ Idea (Eclipse has something similar) and on typing your template word the IDE will replace this word with the propper code, or use project Lombok and define a simple [`@Log`, `@Slf4j`, ...](https://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) annotation on class level

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your exact problem you are solving or use case you are wanting for your application.

Is it that you just don't want to create the static Logger field or that you don't want to have to type out the `SimpleClass.class` in the code?

By already describing a potential solution it is making it hard for one answer to be the right one to satisfy your problem / use case.

Comment: I don't want to type it everytime that I need in my code. even with MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass()‌​ or this.class I need to define it. it's a boilerplate code beging repeated everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use Lombok @log varient in your project, it will automatically set at compile time

If you are using slf4j use @Slf4j

It's best approach and even spring uses internally in some projects

Comment: This might be a good solution. Do I need to define a log variable inside the class or it adds it?

Comment: Also how IDE treat it. Do they know the variables like log and getter/setters or I need to do some extra work around?

Comment: In IDE once you add lombok double click on jar and it will ask for IDE location, then set it . after that clean start IDE it will automatically takes values

Comment: sample usage is https://github.com/rajadilipkolli/Springboot-webapplication-project-skeleton/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/web/controller/UserController.java#L18

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `@Log` annotation.

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {}
```

Now implement the `BeanPostProcessor` which gives us the `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method which allows us to manage a bean before initialization. We search for the `@Log` annotation and inject an implementation with the `LoggerFactory`.

```
@Component
public class LoggerPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass());
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                field.set(bean, log);
            }
        }, new ReflectionUtils.FieldFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Field field) {
                return field.isAnnotationPresent(Log.class);
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

And use the `@Log` annotation at field level to describe that we want to inject a logger.

```
@Log
private Logger logger;
```