# Kotlin extension log function with logback(slf4j)

Tags: kotlin, logback, slf4j, extension-function

I have create an extension function for logging:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

fun Any.log(msg: String) {
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass.name).debug(msg)
}
```

But i'm not sure about will it be init any time when it will be called or not, because method `LoggerFactory.getLogger` invoking `getILoggerFactory`.

Mb someone already did something like that and can assure me that it's won't be any memory leaks :) ?

For now i using old fashion approach(of declaring logger field in a class):

```
companion object {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest::class.java.name)
}
```

but a simple `unit` test like this:

```
@Test
fun testLogger() {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    for (i in 0..999) {
        log("i=" + i)
    }
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val time = end - start
    println("*** TIME=" + time.toDouble() / 1000 + " sec")
}
```

shows same result as with old fashion option:

```
@Test
fun testLogger() {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    for (i in 0..999) {
        logger.debug("i=" + i)
    }
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val time = end - start
    println("*** TIME=" + time.toDouble() / 1000 + " sec")
}

companion object {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest::class.java.name)
}
```

~ `*** TIME=0.02 sec`

I'm using:

```
org.slf4j - 1.7.25
ch.qos.logback - 1.2.3
```

Comment: It seems like `LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)` does not construct a new logger each times and is able to re-use them, but, as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924399/2196460), the calls are not free, so you should not do it that way.

Comment: Maybe there is another option to make an extension kotlin function with logback?

Comment: If you use `Any.foo() { do sth with javaClass }` and call it like `String.foo()`, then `javaClass` should be `String` or `Any` (I'm not sure), but definitely not the calling class. However, compared to the old-fashioned way this doesn't give you the same result

Comment: Actually I'd probably go with `interface HasLogger { val logger : Logger }` and define `HasLogger.log()`. Although this still requires one logger per instance and not one logger per class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For logging, I could recommend another solution.

First, add interface ILogging and class LoggingImpl:

```
interface ILogging {
    val log: Logger
}

class LoggingImp(loggerImpl: Logger) : ILogging {
    override val log: Logger = loggerImpl

    companion object {
        operator inline fun <reified T> invoke(): LoggingImp {
            return LoggingImp(LoggerFactory.getLogger(T::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

And now you could add logger to any class using Kotlin delegation:

```
class TestClass : ILogging by LoggingImp<TestClass>() {
    fun test() {
        log.info("test")
    }
}
```

Logger will be created when create parent object. Example of usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testClass = TestClass()

    testClass.test()
}
```

Hope, this will help you.